# Difference between inline SQL and selecting from view

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Are there any significant performance differences in PHP and MySQL between 'building' an SQL statement inline (or 'hard-coding' it) and selecting from a MySQL view?

For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT `table1`.`field1`,`table1`.`field2`,`table2`.`field1`,`table2`.`field2` 
        FROM `table1` 
            RIGHT JOIN `table2` On `table1`.`field1` = `table2`.`field1`;";
```

versus

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `view1`;";
```

where `view1` is actually the same statement.

Comment: In that instance, there should be no differences.

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking ti yourself?

Comment: Build your code base how it makes sense to, then measure and see if you need to improve. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Comment: Hooray for RIGHT JOIN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance of views is complex. MySQL doesn't yet have all the optimization tricks of other RDMSs for optimizing queries from views.

For example, read this:  http://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/  It's dated, but will give you a view to the issues.

If MySQL can handle your view using query merge -- that is, by internally expanding your query so the logic of the view is embedded within it -- it will be able to optimize it just as if you wrote your view logic into the query. This is probably true of the example in your question. In this case the cost of using the view is small or nil.

If not, then it creates an internal temporary table-like data structure containing the view. That table-like data structure *has no indexes*, so it will have to be handled as a whole to deal with such things as `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses. That may do damage to your performance.

There's no way to find out this stuff for sure without trying it. Not only should you use `EXPLAIN` on your queries, you should actually measure their performance, to make decisions about how to write your views and queries for acceptable performance.

The best thing to do is get your application working, and then optimize it. If you're lucky enough to have your application scale up (get lots of users and data) you'll need to revisit the optimization as your tables get bigger and bigger.

Comment: How would I know which of these situations - query merge or temporary table - MySQL is using?

Comment: If 'EXPLAIN` says "temporary" or "filesort" that means `EXPLAIN` predicts your query will use a temporary table strategy.

Comment: Will MySQL always use the same approach or can it choose between temporary and merge on the same query?

Comment: @Warwick, MySQL's query planner uses its current snapshot of the state of the database (statistics, etc) when it figures out what to do. That can change over time. `EXPLAIN` gives you, basically, a forecast. What counts? Whether your performance goals are met.  What doesn't count? Whether EXPLAIN mentions filesort.